# How do I subtract one query result from another?

Tags: sql, oracle

The procedure compiles just fine, but when I pass in a username (the username is valid too), I get the following error I know that the subtraction isn't returning a value, but why? Here's the error:

> ````
> ORA-06512: at "KOBS24.ADD_PAYMENT", line 5
> 01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to insert NULL into previously listed objects.
> *Action:   These objects cannot accept NULL values.```
> ````

Here is my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE add_payment(username2 VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO user_pay VALUES(
    user_pay_seq.nextval,
        (SELECT offer_price FROM users_pending WHERE username = username2),
            ((SELECT veh_price FROM vehicle_table WHERE lot_id = (SELECT pend_lot_id FROM users_pending WHERE username = username2)) - 
                (SELECT offer_price FROM users_pending WHERE username = username2)),
                    (SELECT pay_id FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE lot_id = 
                    (SELECT lot_id FROM VEHICLE_TABLE WHERE lot_id =
                        (SELECT pay_id FROM users_pending WHERE username = username2)))
);
UPDATE VEHICLE_TABLE
SET
   veh_status = 'owned',
    owner_user = username2
    WHERE (SELECT username FROM users_pending) = username2;
END;
```

Comment: If any value could be `NULL`, use `NVL` or `DECODE` on that field to replace `NULL` with `0` or some other value.

Comment: First change it, so that the target columns for the `INSERT` are explicitly listed. Maybe it's just a non matching order of columns and values. And try to format or formulate it in a more readable way.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the question tags and include the structure of each of the tables mentioned in your queries - that is, all field names and data types. Thanks.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find your misunderstanding.

Comment: When clear this will likely be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from your query, but my best interpretation of what you're attempting to do is

```
SELECT NVL(up.OFFER_PRICE, 0),
       NVL(vt.VEH_PRICE, 0) - NVL(up.OFFER_PRICE, 0),
       NVL(ut.PAY_ID, 0)
  FROM USERS_PENDING up
  INNER JOIN VEHICLE_TABLE vt
    ON vt.PEND_LOT_ID = up.LOT_ID
  INNER JOIN USERS_TABLE ut
    ON ut.LOT_ID = vt.LOT_ID
  WHERE up.USERNAME = username2
```

Without test data or expected results to work from I can't be too confident this is correct, but it's the best I can do based on what you posted.